# JSF 2.0 Forbid calling action after failed validation in actionListener

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, action, actionlistener

I have a dialog for adding some data:

```html
<p:commandButton id="save" 
    actionListener="#{adminNationalController.saveTeam}" 
    action="#{adminManageInternationalTournamentController.updateTeamList}"
    value="#{msg.save}" ajax="true"
    icon="ui-icon-check"
    onmousedown="return validateSubmit('addCombinedTeamForm', ['name'],'lang')"
    oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) addCombinedTeamDialog.hide()"
    process = "@form"
    update="lang, name, :manageTournament:dataList,:manageTournament:scroll, :menuForm:growl, :manageTournament:nationalTeam">

    <f:setPropertyActionListener 
        value="#{adminNationalController.newTeamBean}"
        target="#{adminManageInternationalTournamentController.newTeamBean}"/>

</p:commandButton>
```

In `saveTeam` I try to validate data but `action` case in case validation failed.

Is it posible forbid calling action?

Answer (score 8):

From an action listener, you're supposed to throw `AbortProcessingException` when you want to abort the processing of the remaining action listeners and the final action.

However, better would be to use a real `Validator` on the input component. This way the whole invoke action phase will be bypassed.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener/3909382#3909382)

Answer (score 1):

In your `saveTeam` if validation fails you can call [FacesContext#renderResponse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#renderResponse%28%29) on your current `FacesContext` instance to skip all the subsequent phases and go to *render response* phase.

Just add the line bellow:

```
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
```

in case of validation fails in `saveTeam`.

***Edit:***

My suggestion will be to use a real `validator` for *validation purpose*.